# New Column added to a table doesnt show up in query

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

I am adding a new column to an existing table and adding a new entry to the table with valid data present only in new column (other column being 0 by default)

Adding Column :

```
        final String DB_ADD_COLUMN_STATEMENT_TABLE_SHOP_NAME =
                "ALTER TABLE "+ shopName + " ADD COLUMN "+ "D" + time + " FLOAT";
        try {
            mDB.beginTransaction();
            //SQLiteStatement statement = mDB.compileStatement(DB_ADD_COLUMN_STATEMENT_TABLE_SHOP_NAME);
            //statement.execute();
            mDB.execSQL(DB_ADD_COLUMN_STATEMENT_TABLE_SHOP_NAME);
            mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"addItemSample : Exception while adding column to table!!");
        }
        finally {
            mDB.endTransaction();
        }
```

Adding a new entry to the table with data only in this column succeeds.

But when I query the table , this new column doesn't show up in the cursor.

Though the adding column and querying happen in different threads, they are serialized from the way they are being called from my code (ie first column is added and then db is queried) and also the I am using a single connection to db.

I wondering what might be reason for this?

PS:When db query is performed immediately after inserting the column  , it shows up.

Comment: what about the '+ "D" +' in DB_ADD_COLUMN_STATEMENT_TABLE_SHOP_NAME? Is it on purpose or a mistake?

Comment: It is on purpose , I just prefix D to time as sqlite doesnt accept column name begining with a number

Answer (score 0):

depends on your query statement.
is it like

```
String query="select id, column1, column 2 from "+shopName+" where yourcondition";
```

?
may be you have to add column?

```
String query="select id, column1, column2, D192200 from "+shopName+"";
```

or you may query all columns

```
String query="select * from "+shopName+"";
```

Comment: I just query for all entries from the table.

Comment: Have you saved any value in that column before the query?

Comment: Yes , it is saved and if I dump db I can see that value

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that you are adding a column that expects `NOT NULL` values

Try something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE "+ shopName + " ADD COLUMN  "+ "D" + time + " FLOAT" default 0 NOT NULL;
```

Use which ever default value you need and update the values as needed.